# How to stop Openapi-generator-maven-plugin creates putItem method for type: object

Tags: java, openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin, jakarta-migration

EDIT: Bug report github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/16245

(I am not quite sure if this is related to jakarta usage, or open api version, but problem seems to be starting around version 5.3.0)

After migrating jaxb to jakarta package, I see some of the created java classes (by openapi-generator) has errors, I see methods that should not be there (I compare with jaxb version classes and this 'putTypeItem' doesn't exist in old versions). if they must be there, then they should be created properly

Note the error in 'typeItem' in method parameters below, there is no type! And this method do not exist in jaxb version. I have compilation errors:

```
  public GetResponse putTypeItem(String key,  **typeItem**) {
    if (this.type == null) {
      this.type = new HashMap<>();
    }
    this.type.put(key, typeItem);
    return this;
  }
```

This is my plugin config:

```
 <plugin>
        <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
        <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>6.6.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>generate</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <inputSpec>${basedir}/../management-swagger.yaml</inputSpec>
              <generateApis>false</generateApis>
              <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
              <generateApiDocumentation>false</generateApiDocumentation>
              <generateModelDocumentation>false</generateModelDocumentation>
              <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
              <generateSupportingFiles>false</generateSupportingFiles>
              <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
              <configOptions>
                <useJakartaEe>true</useJakartaEe>
                <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
              </configOptions>
              <modelPackage>com.client.model</modelPackage>
              <typeMappings>
                <typeMapping>Double=java.math.BigDecimal</typeMapping>
              </typeMappings>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

and this is how my yaml looks like:

```
GetResponse:
  properties:
    id:
      type: string
      example: 
      description: 
    type:
      type: object
      description: 
      properties:
        code:
          type: string
          description: '
        description:
          type: string
          description:
```

Openapi-generator-maven-plugin sees the property 'type' object and tries create a put method for it, which I dont need, also it cant create propely.

How to fix this?

Comment: Few clarifications questions. 1. what do you mean by "After migrating jaxb to jakarta package""? were you using jaxb (pre jakarta)? 2. what is the open api version? 3. Does this generates xml annotations? (based on configuration it should not) 4. Will you be able to provide complete open api spec? (complete but only with necessary parts)

Comment: @RuwankaDeSilva Hi, you can see in my bug report in more detail. https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/16245

Answer (score 0):

As also stated in the GitHub bug report page. Problem was solved by adding a special REFACTOR_ALLOF_WITH_PROPERTIES_ONLY flag using OpenApi normalizer and using latest version:

Example:

java -jar modules/openapi-generator-cli/target/openapi-generator-cli.jar generate -g java -i modules/openapi-generator/src/test/resources/3_0/allOf_extension_parent.yaml -o /tmp/java-okhttp/ --openapi-normalizer REFACTOR_ALLOF_WITH_PROPERTIES_ONLY=true

Or

```
                         <openapiNormalizer>
                            REFACTOR_ALLOF_WITH_PROPERTIES_ONLY=true
                         </openapiNormalizer>
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the plugin uses the JAXB annotations to generate the constructors, that are not available in Jakarta.Try adding below configuration to plugin and do a `mvn clean install`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>6.6.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <generateJakartaCompatibleClient>true</generateJakartaCompatibleClient>
    </configuration>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thx but that didnt help